How to compare two dataframes according to values and column headers in Pandas?
I want to add columns with values for specified sample lists to one df (df_sets)  according to column headers from the second df (df_counts), depending on gene_id parameter, and calculate the mean.
A tiny part of my input data:
import pandas as pd

d_sets = {'gene_id': ['g0', 'g2', 'g3'], 
          'set_1': [['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28',], ['P1-6', 'P1-12', 'P1-25'], ['P1-6', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']]}
df_sets = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d_sets)

d_counts = {'gene_id': ['g0', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3'],
            'P1-6': [1, 2, 5, 7],
            'P1-12': [2, 4, 6, 5],
            'P1-25': [5, 1, 2, 6],
            'P1-28': [3, 8, 1, 2]}
df_counts = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d_counts)

I've started by splitting sample lists into separate columns and merging dfs on gene_id :
df_sets[['1_1', '1_2', '1_3']] = pd.DataFrame(df_sets.set_1.tolist(), index=df_sets.index)
df_merged = df_sets.merge(df_counts, on='gene_id')

and it looks like this:
  gene_id                  set_1    1_1    1_2    1_3  P1-6  P1-12  P1-25  P1-28
0      g0  [P1-12, P1-25, P1-28]  P1-12  P1-25  P1-28     1      2      5      3
1      g2   [P1-6, P1-12, P1-25]   P1-6  P1-12  P1-25     5      6      2      1
2      g3   [P1-6, P1-25, P1-28]   P1-6  P1-25  P1-28     7      5      6      2

but I have no idea how to step forward or maybe it's the wrong way to achieve the desired output:
  gene_id                  set_1   P1-6  P1-12  P1-25  P1-28  mean_set_1
0      g0  [P1-12, P1-25, P1-28]    NaN      2      5      3      3.3333
1      g2   [P1-6, P1-12, P1-25]      5      6      2    NaN      4.3333
2      g3   [P1-6, P1-25, P1-28]      7    NaN      6      2         5.0


Here's one approach:
out = df_sets.merge(df_counts, on='gene_id', how='left')

m = out['set_1'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies().astype(bool)

out.loc[:, m.columns] = out.loc[:, m.columns].where(m)

out['mean_set_1'] = out.loc[:, m.columns].mean(axis=1)

Output:
  gene_id                  set_1  P1-6  P1-12  P1-25  P1-28  mean_set_1
0      g0  [P1-12, P1-25, P1-28]   NaN    2.0      5    3.0    3.333333
1      g2   [P1-6, P1-12, P1-25]   5.0    6.0      2    NaN    4.333333
2      g3   [P1-6, P1-25, P1-28]   7.0    NaN      6    2.0    5.000000

Explanation / Intermediates

Apply df.merge with on='gene_id' and how='left'.
Apply one-hot encoding on column 'set_1' using Series.str.join + Series.str.get_dummies + Series.astype.

m

   P1-12  P1-25  P1-28   P1-6 # note that col order is (probably) not yet correct!
0   True   True   True  False
1   True   True  False   True
2  False   True   True   True

(If performance is a concern, check here for alternative methods for this step.)

Use df.loc + df.where to replace values with NaN where False.
Add row-wise mean via df.mean on axis=1.


N.B. If you run the risk that set_1 has no match for one or more 'P1-*' columns, make sure to use df.reindex. E.g. suppose, we have:
d_counts = {'gene_id': ['g0', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3'],
            'P1-6': [1, 2, 5, 7],
            'P1-12': [2, 4, 6, 5],
            'P1-25': [5, 1, 2, 6],
            'P1-28': [3, 8, 1, 2],
            'P1-30': [3, 8, 1, 2], # < not present in `set_1`
            }
df_counts = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d_counts)

Then you could add:
# ...

m = out['set_1'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies().astype(bool)
m = m.reindex(df_counts.columns[1:], axis=1)

# ...


Very nice answer. If there are many duplicated gene_id, it might be more efficient to first generate the dummies on the unique values present in the two inputs, then perform the merge.
